# SuiteCRM data modelling: Direct Reports?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using SuiteCRM 7.5.3. People with knowledge of SugarCRM CE up to version 6.5 are also welcome to answer, as the answers should apply to both systems.

I'm trying to do some data modelling, fitting my data to the Sugar/Suite concepts.

What I know about **the "Direct Reports" relationship**: it's a one-to-many relationship linking two Contacts.

This means that a certain contact can have many people who are his "direct reports", but each person can only report directly to a single manager.

**What I don't know, and would like to ask**: are there any other less apparent semantics taking effect, or does SuiteCRM simply record the relationship, display it, and do nothing more about it?

Things like: the manager being able to access certain records of his direct reports; or notifications to the manager of things happening to the direct reports; or any change in the logic of record assignment, etc.

Anything will be useful to know, even if it only a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late in answering this, so don't know whether it will be helpful or not. I'm an open source developer and freelancer who is studying the SuiteCRM architecture, so I'll answer your question from that perspective.

> What I know about the "Direct Reports" relationship: it's a one-to-many relationship linking two Contacts.

Yes, its a one-to-many, meaning one manager can have multiple subordinates, but not vice-versa. In the database, however, they are not maintained as separate tables of employee and subordinates, its just a single `contacts` table with a single field called `reports_to_id`:

```
desc contacts;
...
| assistant           
| assistant_phone     
| lead_source         
| **reports_to_id**
| birthdate           
...
```

From `reports_to_id` field, the system knows that who is the line manager of this current contact/employee and displays on the contacts screen accordingly. So yeah, presently it just seems like it is only used to map a contact with their subordinates for display. If this field is having any repercussions anywhere else in the system, then I don't know about it yet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already knew all of this, but I thank you for your efforts anyway. Maybe somebody else might learn from your answer. Meanwhile, please come back and add information if you learn anything more. I promise to do the same.